# TypeError: token must be of type str, not NoneType

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with python but I get this error when I run it:

```
TypeError: token must be of type str, not NoneType
```

If you want to see my code, here is it:

```
import discord
import os
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

client = discord.Bot()
token = os.getenv('Token')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as a bot {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split("#")[0]
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    user_message = str(message.content)

    print(f'Message {user_message} by {username} on {channel}')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if channel == "random":
        if user_message.lower() == "hello" or user_message.lower() == "hi":
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == "bye":
            await message.channel.send(f'Bye {username}')
        elif user_message.lower() == "tell me a joke":
            jokes = [" Can someone please shed more\
            light on how my lamp got stolen?",
                    "Why is she called llene? She\
                    stands on equal legs.",
                    "What do you call a gazelle in a \
                    lions territory? Denzel."]
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(jokes))

client.run(token)
```

My bot token is fake because I don't want anyone know it's token. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you have envvar named `"MTAwNjA1NTQ4NTg3MjUzNzcwMQ.GcPn03.xeIRE4c1W0OF8aNtkA4hj1Nl2V6mowLV1BqWuU"`? Also, congrats, your token is now public.

Comment: The problem starts in line number 9 . It seems like you think that os.getenv receives an argument that it's the value of the token, which is wrong. You need to pass the key of the environment variable

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859138/getting-discord-bot-token-from-env-file-in-python (i.e. use an .env file for your token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your discord bot is hosted locally, without needing to be shared publicly or hosted online, you may simply set token variable directly to the string of your token.

```
token = 'MTAwNjA1NTQ4NTg3MjUzNzcwMQ.GcPn03.xeIRE4c1W0OF8aNtkA4hj1Nl2V6mowLV1BqWuU'
```

If you would like to make use of environment variables to keep your bot token secure, (usually when you would like to run your discord bot online), the argument passed into os.getenv() should be the key which you set in the environment variables.

Comment: I still have the error:
`discord.errors.HTTPException: 405 Method Not Allowed (error code: 0): 405: Method Not Allowed`(I already said this token is fake)

Comment: which line did the error point to? @Tom

Answer (score 0):

Your token value should be got from env var name:

And if the token is None, then don't do anything else, because your program cannot run without token

```py
token = os.getenv('MY_TOKEN_VAR')
if not token:
    print('ERROR: Token var is missing: MY_TOKEN_VAR')
    sys.exit(-1)
```