# Getting Discord Bot Token from Env File in Python

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, keyerror, env-file

I have a folder which has a few files: Procfile, requirements.txt, main.py and secret.env. Secret.env has one line of code in it:

```
TOKEN = "my bot token"
```

"My bot token" is my Discord token. Now, in main.py, I want to get access to this token from the environment file so I can run my bot. However, I'm not very sure how to do it. I imported os and tried the following:

```
bot.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

However, I get a KeyError when running this. Anyone know how to resolve this? I'm using VSCode and am on a Windows device. Do I need to use the dotenv module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solution :)

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
# ...
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Be sure to name your file ".env" and just that, and that it is in the same folder as your .py file.

EDIT : some editors don't manage that ".env" file, prefer to run it in console directly.

Comment: Hello, I tried this, but I now get a new error, which says "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'. Edit: fixed  it by importing load_dotenv from dotenv module and running that.

Comment: You're right, you need to import os and dotenv both to use .env file.